# scipy.stats.probplot raised `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'shape'`

Tags: python, scipy.stats

I tried to plot QQ plot by using `stats.probplot`, but raised AttributeError.

My code is simply to call a QQ plot which is:

```py
stats.probplot(
    df['col'], 
    dist="norm", 
    plot=pylab
    )
pylab.show()
```

Then it raised `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'shape'`

My data frame is looked like this:
[image]